# Can not start GUI program in vscode command context

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I using extension API to create vscode command to launch a GUI program.

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('rnk.inspect', () => {
    require('child_process').exec('react-devtools', (err, stdout) => {
        console.log('result', err, stdout)
    })
});
```

But when I run this command, I get output:

```
result Error: Command failed: react-devtools
extension.js:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:287:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe.Socket._destroy.cb._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:554:12)
```

I've installed `react-devtools`, and the following code works as standalone node app:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec('react-devtools');
```

It also works correctly in vscode's integrated terminal with command `react-devtools`.

All the code above are ran on Mac.

What's the problem? Is there any differences between the node environment in vscode extension and the regular node?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by unsetting the `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE` environment variable:

```
exec('react-devtools', {env: {...process.env, ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE:''}}, (err, stdout) => {
    console.log('result', err, stdout);
});
```

Refer to: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76673